# Python simple print error

Tags: python

Just by doing `print "Hello world"`
I get this error:

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Yet, I'm using the Python GUI for windows.

Answer (score 8):

That syntax is no longer valid in Python 3.

```
  File "prog.py", line 1
    print "Hello world"
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

[ideone](http://ideone.com/bEVzfe)

In **Python 2** `print` was a keyword and the code you tried is correct.

```
# Python 2
print "Hello world"
```

In **Python 3** `print` is a function and your code no longer works. The correct syntax is as follows:

```
# Python 3
print("Hello world!")
```

**Related**

- [What’s New In Python 3.0](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html)

Comment: Thanks Mark! Looks like a wannabe c++. :)